# Rename file using sbt-assembly

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I have a scala project that uses the `ConfigFactory` to set up the application configurations. For building I use `sbt` (together with `sbt-assembly`).

Depending on whether I create an assembly with `sbt-assembly` or whether I just run the project, I would like to use different config files (`application.conf` when running the project, `assembly.conf` when running the assembly of the project).

I thought of using the `assemblyMergeStrategy` for this purpose: When assembling the jar, I would discard the `application.conf` and rename `assembly.conf`. My idea was something like:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("application.conf") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case PathList("assembly.conf") => MergeStrategy.rename
  ...
}
```

By this I would like to achieve is that when assembling the jar, the file `assembly.conf` is renamed to `application.conf` and is therefore used by `ConfigFactory`, whereas the original `application.conf` is discarded.

The code above obviously does not work, as I cannot specify to what filename `assembly.conf` should be renamed to. How can I achieve this?

Comment: did you ever get this working?  i'm looking to do the same thing

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your own MergeStrategy(in `project` directory) that will rename files to `application.conf` and then redefine `assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly` to discard original `application.conf` and apply `MyMergeStrategy` to `assembly.conf`:

```
import java.io.File   
import sbtassembly.MergeStrategy

class MyMergeStrategy extends MergeStrategy{
  override def name: String = "Rename to application.conf"

  override def apply(tempDir: File, path: String, files: Seq[File]): Either[String, Seq[(File, String)]] = {
    Right(files.map(_ -> "application.conf"))
  }
}
```

And then use in build.sbt:

```
val root = (project in file(".")).settings(Seq(
  assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
    case PathList("application.conf") => MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("assembly.conf") => new MyMergeStrategy()
    case x =>
      val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
      oldStrategy(x)
  }
))
```

This will do just for your case but for more complicated cases I would read how they do it in sbt-native-packager:
https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/recipes/package_configuration.html