# SBT: Rename a project file before its added to Fat Jar

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly, sbt-plugin

I have a file by the name 'app.settings' which I have to rename to 'settings.conf' before it's packaged as a part of Uber Jar.
I am using SBT assembly plugin to create Fat jar.

Does Uber Jar allow me to rename files? Or is there another way?

Comment: I see that it is a little bit old, but [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54170506/4299386) should answer this question too.